# Transparent box that cuts through box behind it

Tags: html, css, stack, z-index, division

Is there some way I can get the box not show the pink? That is have all the area within the box show the blue of the body? Ideally the solution not being something where I make four pink divs around the box but using the divs I already have. Maybe some tricky using z-index? Also I need it to show the actual body background. Changing the background color of the box to blue won't work. Thanks.

```css
body {
  background-color: azure;
}

#pink {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  z-index: -1;
}

#box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 45%;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  background-color: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id='pink'></div>
<div id='box'></div>
```

Comment: you want to create a hole inside the pink?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, the only way to somehow achieve this is by giving it `background-color: inherit`.

The property `z-index` will never place anything behind the `<body />` tag because it is above it's hierarchy in the DOM.

You want it to be see through whenever the box is placed over the pink right?

Comment: yeah, so whenever anything passes through the box it doesn't show up in its transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-color:inherit` property since it will be inherited from the father element which has the azure background.

```
#box {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
left: 45%;
border: 1px dotted black;
background-color: inherit;
}
```